# How to get RTSPtoWeb to work with with https

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, rtsp

We have installed RTSPtoWeb on a spare server on our network, just to see if it works, and it does. It captures the stream from our cameras nicely. I then used the webrtc stream option to successfully show it on a webpage, BUT only in my local development environemt on localhost. The spare server does not have an SSL certificate, it's just http.

Now, of course this needs to work in our production environment too, which is all https. At first, I just pointed to the spare http-server. So, naturally Chrome throws the mixed-content error. I then tried to install RTSPtoWeb on the production server, but I guess I still need to somehow apply the production servers SSL certificate to RTSPtoWeb. If I point to the RTSPtoWeb with a https protocol, it returns the Net ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

In the config.json, there are a number of https related variables, but there is no documentation on what they actually mean:

```
 "https": true,
 "https_auto_tls": false,
 "https_auto_tls_name": "",
 "https_cert": "server.crt",
 "https_key": "server.key",
```

Has anyone had any luck using RTSPtoWeb with an SSL certificate, and if so, how? Or might there be a quick and dirty way to circumvent the "mixed-content" issue in Chrome.

Or, since we are working on the production server, and I'm just using the IP-address to point to RTSPtoWeb, would it change anything if RTSPtoWeb was referenced using the domain name of the server? We use Apache, so could I just redirect traffic somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I spent a great deal of time figuring this one out as well, you probably aren't working on it anymore but here's the answer for legacy purposes.

1. Register your A record
   Ensure that your public IP is registered as an A record on your domain registrar
   Instead of using just IP-address to point to RTSPtoWeb, use an A record that points to your public IP
   e.g https://rtsptoweb.yourdomain.com:12629/stream/0/channel/0/webrtc
   instead of https://100.100.100:12629/stream/0/channel/0/webrtc
2. SSL Certificates missing
   Ensure your server.crt and server.key files are getting included properly in the build. I used docker to build and had to edit the docker file in order to include the files correctly.

Your SSL cert has to be generated and certified for the A record which you registered earlier.

Lastly after launching RTSPtoWeb do scrutinize the logs to understand what's not working, it'll point you in the right direction.